# put the dynamic data in dropdown list using select2.js

Tags: html, json, jquery-select2

I am tried to get the data from my file using ajax in select2.js. I want to get data according the value which I entered in my textbox and append that value in my dropdown using select2. I tried for that but it didn't give the result according my search keyword how to solve these problem.

Here is my input box on HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="Address1" name="Address1" >
```

Javascript Code

```
<script>    
$("#Address1").select2({
    tags: [],
    ajax: {
        url: 'ajaxhandler.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        // quietMillis: 50,
        data: function (term) {
            return {
                term: term
            };
        },
        results: function (term) {

        } 
    }
});
</script>
```

ajaxhandler.php

```
<?php
$CITIES = array("Ahmedabad", "Mumbai", "USA", "Canada", "Pune");
echo json_encode($CITIES); exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Data format for Select2.js (version 4) is:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

See: https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

So you need to [processResults](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data) received form server like below:

```
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data.items, function(obj, index) {
          return { id: index, text: obj };
        })
      };
    },
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/cwb9r23b/