# JSON won't display in custom template

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a Select2 box which successfully searches via PHP and returns a JSON result, but won't display properly. All I get is "undefined – undefined". [Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pof33.png)

This is the JSON being returned: `{"hash":"5304c7399a0e169572b01d1123db3de3","donorname":"John Smith","nbid":"4"}`

This is my Javascript call to Select2:

```
function formatdonorList (data) {
  var donors = "<div class='select2-result-listsitory clearfix'>" +
    "<div class='select2-result-listsitory__meta'>" +
      "<div class='select2-result-listsitory__title'>" + data.donorname + " &mdash; " + data.hash + "</div>";
    "</div>";
  return donors;
}

function formatdonorListSelection (list) {
  return list.donorname;
}   

$(".donorsearch").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: "/list-donor-data.php",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
      //var paramsterm = params.term;
      return {
        query: params.term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: data,
      };

    },
    cache: true
  },
  escapeMarkup: function (donors) { return donors; },
  minimumInputLength: 1,
  templateResult: formatdonorList,
  templateSelection: formatdonorListSelection
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: The data format is not correct, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48181139/put-the-dynamic-data-in-dropdown-list-using-select2-js/48183278?s=1|0.0000#48183278

Comment: Have you solved?

Comment: Apologies - no. I have the same code that works with this JSON, so I don't think that's the cause? 

`[{"id":"1","organisation_name":"Org 1","grant_status_name":"Remitted","grant_type_name":"Grant","amount":"$5,000","date_updated":"2w&nbsp;ago"}, {"id":"2","organisation_name":"Org 2","grant_status_name":"Remitted","grant_type_name":"Grant","amount":"$13,200","date_updated":"3mo&nbsp;ago"}, {"id":"3","organisation_name":"Org 1","grant_status_name":"Remitted","grant_type_name":"Grant","amount":"$6,000","date_updated":"3mo&nbsp;ago"}]`

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Data format for Select2.js](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats) (version 4) and see that an **`id` field is necessary**.

So [processResults](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data) must be adapted:

```
    processResults: function (data) {
      return {
        results: $.map(data.results, function(obj, index) {
          return {
            id: obj.nbid,
            donorname: obj.donorname,
            hash: obj.hash
          };
        })
      };
    },
```

Here is a fiddle (ajax simulated): http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/v9bz0xfw/

*P.S.: in jsFiddle simulation data are ajax POSTed to an `/echo/` service and returned as data.results; adapt to your case*